# GSON Parsing without condition

Tags: java, android, gson, android-volley

order_items are ok in first object {}
but in second {} order items are now multiple. with "0" "1" "2"
This come when there are multiple order items.

How to parse it in Java. I tried with One Order with OrderItem as a List property but parsing error comes.

[image: JSON code with two order objects. Inside you can see order item and Items]

Thanks.

Comment: You can get the JSONArray of OrderItems and if its length>1 parse following items using loop

Answer (score 0):

Your json structure is not good but below code will handle it. (Your json structure is bad because it should return a json object when it has one item but it returns an array. Also it should return an array when there are more then one order items but it returns different objects for items.)

```
String orders = "[{\"order_items\":[{\"product_id\":\"1\",\"title\":\"product_1\"}]},{\"order_items\":{\"0\":{\"product_id\":\"2\",\"title\":\"product_2\"},\"1\":{\"product_id\":\"3\",\"title\":\"product_3\"}}}]";

JsonArray baseJsonArray = new JsonParser().parse(orders).getAsJsonArray();


Gson gson = new Gson();

if (baseJsonArray != null && baseJsonArray.size() > 0) {

    List<OrderItem> orderItemList = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

    for (JsonElement jsonElement : baseJsonArray) {
        JsonElement ordersJsonElement = ((JsonObject) jsonElement).get("order_items");

        if (ordersJsonElement instanceof JsonArray) {
            JsonArray orderItemsJsonArray = (JsonArray) ordersJsonElement;

            for (JsonElement orderItemJsonObject : orderItemsJsonArray) {
                OrderItem orderItem = gson.fromJson(orderItemJsonObject, OrderItem.class);
                orderItemList.add(orderItem);
            }

        } else if (ordersJsonElement instanceof JsonObject) {
            JsonObject orderItemJsonObject = (JsonObject) ordersJsonElement;

            int jsonTag = 0;

            while (true) {
                JsonElement orderItemJsonElement = orderItemJsonObject.get(String.valueOf(jsonTag));
                if (orderItemJsonElement == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    OrderItem orderItem = gson.fromJson(orderItemJsonElement, OrderItem.class);
                    orderItemList.add(orderItem);
                }

                jsonTag++;
            }

        }
    }
```

OrderItem pojo class:

```
static class OrderItem {
    String product_id, title, quantity, product_picture;
}
```